# Visual Studio build error with ".Netstandard 2.0"?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-standard

I just added a library to my WPF project. The library dependencies are framework4.6 and .netstandard 2.

When I tried to build the project I got this error:

> Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.WinFx.targets(268,9): error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' because the parent does not exist.'

I have imported netstandard nuget package in my project.  I tried to add a reference to netstandard, however, I could not find it in the list of assemblies so  I browsed to the location and added the reference. Yet when I try to compile the project I get the same error. Any ideas on this error would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio do you use? For VS2015 you need to upgrade NuGet Package Manager, while VS2017 you need to upgrade to 15.3.x. Then remove and re-add those packages, and NuGet can properly handle the reference, and show you a more meaningful error message. You also need to install .NET Core SDK 2.0 from http://dot.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to target .netstandard 2.0 with standard framework, you must target at least .net 4.6.1 as shown in the following chart.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard

Which specific library did you add?

Comment: It is a class library called zstd (a compression method). I built the library targeting .NetFramework7, but the error is still there!

Comment: Still having exactly the same error with 4.7.2 and a brand new Visual 2017. This is not exactly the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same problem (against .NET 4.7.2 and Visual 15.8.x) by :

- removing the 2013 directive : `<ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>false</ImplicitlyExpandDesignTimeFacades>`
- removing the reference to netstandard.dll from the project.

I also ran a nuget package reinstall because my package versions were mixed between 4.6.2 and 4.7.2 :

- `Update-Package -Reinstall -Project MyProject`